# Adding priority to layout constraints

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a `label` and `button` in a `superView` like this.

```
|--------------[Label]-----[button]-|
```

I'd like the `label` to be `centred` if possible, then have a min gap to the `button` and move to the left.

So if the button is big it looks like...

```
|-[        LABEL!        ]-[button]-|
```

So, the button stays where it is and at the same size. And there are minimum gaps between the elements.

I can add the `centerX` constraint but I can't seem to give it a priority so it remains `Required`.

How can I create this situation? I'm doing all the auto layout in code.

The constraints I currently have are...

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[_label]-(>=8@1000)-[_button(==45)]-|"
                                                             options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:views]];

[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_label
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:self.contentView
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                  constant:0.0]];
```

But I'm not sure how to reduce the priority of the second constraint.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You just set the `priority` property of the constraint, like so:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *centeringConstraint = 
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_label
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:self.contentView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:0.0];

centeringConstraint.priority = 800; // <-- this line

[self addConstraint:centeringConstraint];
```

Comment: Of course! Thanks! I didn't think to create the object before adding it. Perfect! Got it sorted now, thanks!